# Arrows to the middle of a node and increasing the height of a node

Tags: tikz-pgf

Wants to draw the arrows to the middle of the nodes named Chapter 4 and Chapter 5 (highlighted with red in the attached figure).  Please advice.

Please find the written script below

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes,arrows,shadows,patterns, decorations.pathreplacing,intersections,calc,fit,matrix}
\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [->, >=triangle 90]
\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 5mm and 2mm,
box/.style = {text width=1.8cm, align=center, below=1mm},
startstop/.style = {rectangle, draw, semithick, rounded corners=3mm,
    minimum width=#1, minimum height=1cm},
startstop/.default = 6cm
]
\node (Chap1) [startstop, align=center, minimum width=11cm]  {Chapter 1: Introduction};
\node (Chap2) [startstop, below=of Chap1, align=center, minimum width=11cm] {Chapter 2: Survey and Taxonomy};
%
\node (Text3-2) [startstop=15mm, below=7mm of Chap2, minimum width=2cm] {Chapter 3: Resource Provisioning};
\node (Text3-1) [startstop=15mm, below left =of Text3-2, minimum width=2cm, xshift=24mm] {Chapter 4: VM Consolidation};
\node (Text3-3) [startstop=15mm, below right=of Text3-2, minimum width=2cm, xshift=-25mm] {Chapter 5: Correlated Failures};

\draw[arrow](Text3-2) -- ++ (Text3-1);
\draw[arrow](Text3-2) -- ++ (Text3-3);
\draw[arrow](Text3-1) -- ++ (Text3-3);  

\node (Chap3) [startstop, minimum height =3cm, inner xsep=0pt,
fit=(Chap1.west |- Text3-2.north)
(Chap1.east |- Text3-3.south)] {};
\draw[white, line width=2pt]
([yshift=-9mm] Chap3.west) -- ++ (0,18mm)
([yshift=-9mm] Chap3.east) -- ++ (0,18mm);
%
\node (Chap6) [startstop, align=center, below=of Chap3, minimum width=11cm] {Chapter 6: Architecture and Framework};
\node (Chap7) [startstop, below=of Chap6, align=center, minimum width=11cm] {Chapter 7: Conclusions and Future Directions};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the `++` in your arrow drawing commands, and you need to provide a `north` anchor to centre them:

```
\draw[arrow](Text3-2) -- (Text3-1.north);
\draw[arrow](Text3-2) -- (Text3-3.north);
```

Comment: +1 just to prove that Ti*k*Z answers give easy reputation ... ;-)

Comment: @marmot And no picture necessary. :)